# Testing different groups of cucumber selenium tests?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber

Is there any way to divide my cucumber features into different directories with different setups?

I'm creating a 'premium' version of my application with different features enabled behind feature toggles, and I need to somehow figure out how to divide my tests with different grouped setup.

If I could re-write the feature toggles `.js` file before each 'premium' test runs, this would get the job done.

Can cucumber tests be grouped, and be given different setups by group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a great fit for [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags).  You could use a `@premium` tag and apply it to any scenario that is only enabled in the premium version.  You can run different sets of tests as follows:

```
cucumber .  #Run all tests
cucumber . --tags ~@premium  #Run non-premium tests
```

Comment: This looks great for separating features, but can I do setup and teardown based on tag? Is there any way to access the tags being run in `env.rb`, for example?

Comment: Absolutely - you can use [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) to do whatever tag-specific setup and teardown you need.